# Error when trying to call DatePickerFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to show a DatePicker on Android Studio. I have the following code:

```
public class PeopleFragment extends AppFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    //...

    @OnClick(R.id.people_data)
    public void onDateClick() {

        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), PeopleFragment.this, year, month, day);
            }
        };

        dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "DatesPicker");  //error when this line is called

}
```

When I click the button to show the date picker, I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment null must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the `DatePickerFragment` is not a `public static` class. What your code roughly compiles to looks like the following. Note that I left of all non relevant code:

```
public class PeopleFragment {

    private class InnerDatePickerFragment extends DatePickerFragment {

        private PeopleFragment parent;

        InnerDatePickerFragment(PeopleFragment parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    }

    public void onDateClick() {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new InnerDatePickerFragment(this);
    }

}
```

So there are 2 issues with your code:

- The fragment is private. In your case the fragment class is actually only declared inside the method, but using `private` in my code sample is close enough. This is probably also the reason why it says `null` for the Fragment name, because the Fragment class is actually an anonymous inner class.
- The fragment has a reference to the outer `PeopleFragment`.

The limitation that only `public static` classes can be used is a limitation of Android. Due to the Activity and Fragment lifecycle, Android must be able to fully recreate Activites and Fragments instances. In your case it wouldn't be able to do so. There's no way for it to create the private/anonymous Fragment and it wouldn't be able to set the implicit `parent` field.

How can you solve this? Quite easily, either move the `DatePickerFragment` class out of the `PeolpeFragment` class, or make it a `public static` inner class. E.g.

```
public class PeopleFragment {

    public static class InnerDatePickerFragment extends DatePickerFragment {
        // ... your code goes here ...
    }

    public void onDateClick() {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new InnerDatePickerFragment();

        // ... your code goes here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try this in the XML file:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/Birthday"
   custom:font="@string/font_avenir_book"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:editable="false"
   android:hint="@string/birthday"/>
```

> Now in Java File:

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

EditText edittext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Birthday);
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};

edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});
```

> Now add the method in the above activity.

```
private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

> Add android: focusable="false" within the XML file of the EditText to allow for a single touch.